# Powershell Module Install Always Installs Latest Dependency Version

Tags: powershell

Say we have two modules, module1 and module2.  module2 depends on module1.

In module2's psd1 file we have the following:

```
RequiredModules = @(
    @{ModuleName = 'module1'; ModuleVersion = '1.0.0'; }
)
```

which, if I understand the documentation properly, means that we need at least that version, not exactly that version.

We're then building a Docker container to hold and execute them.

```
RUN Install-Module module1 -RequiredVersion 1.0.0
RUN Install-Module module2 -RequiredVersion 1.0.0
```

That all works fine.  But now we implement a new cmdlet in module1 and release version 1.0.1.  When we build the docker image, it ends up with both module1 versions installed, which causes version conflicts.

We put in `Get-Module -ListAvailable` calls before and after the Install-Modules and found that `Install-Module module1` correctly installed v1.0.0, while `Install-Module module2` is installed module2 v1.0.0 but also module1 v1.0.1.

With module v1.0.0 already installed, the RequiredModules for module2 should have already been satisfied.  Why is it installed v1.0.1, and how can I stop it doing that?

Powershell Version: 7.2.5

Comment: This is by design, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.2):  `It's possible to specify a specific version to load using RequiredVersion rather than ModuleVersion. When ModuleVersion is used it will load the newest version available with a minimum of the version specified.`

Comment: Load sure, but install?!  I'd entirely understand if I had 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 installed then Import-Module would load 1.0.1.  Installing the latest seems like a massive overreach.  That said, I'm sure you're right.  It's just crap.